# How do I write universal Swift code for both iOS and macOS. In cocoa I could use #ifdef, what do I do now?

Tags: macros, swift, import, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

For our project we always used one source file for both platforms: iOS and macOS (previously OS X). Right now I am migrating to Swift. Unfortunately there is some files which need

```
import Cocoa
```

and on iOS

```
import UIKit
```

previously we did

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#else
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

How can this be done in Swift? I don't like to write each class twice just because there is no macros anymore.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use:

```
#if os(OSX)
    import Cocoa
#elseif os(iOS)
    import UIKit
#endif
```

Comment: Does that finally mean, that there is still a preprocessor build in with swift?

Comment: Check out "Preprocessor directives" in the manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_20

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this chapter. This is quite helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there an even better way to make it one liner? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Since `os(OSX)` does not work any more on Swift 5/Xcode 12 use:

```
#if os(macOS)
    import Cocoa
#elseif os(iOS)
    import UIKit
#endif
```