# Import Framework Based on Current Target

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I get `Ambiguous use of method` error. The reason is because I have a project with two targets, and the targets use either of two frameworks that have the same methods but with different theme usages.

Based on the selected target, I wish to import a different framework on the same file. For example:

`InitializeViewController.swift`

For Theme A

`import FrameworkX`

For Theme B

`import FrameworkY`

How do I import either framework based on the selected target to avoid ambiguous error? Or is there another better approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26339745/1979882

Comment: `Target` like in `Xcode target`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your target's build settings, **Swift Compiler - Custom Flags** -> **Other Swift Flags**, add a flag for one target, say `-DTargetX`

Then…

```
#if TargetX 
import FrameworkX
#else
import FrameworkY
#endif
```